# "Insert Module" to Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-kernel, nas, portainer

I have installed Docker and Portainer on my Asustor home NAS. This issue appears to be specific to the implementation of Docker/Portainer provided in their app store. I have been working directly with the Portainer staff and they have not seen this issue before.

I have been following instructions from Portainer (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0OvPyJZOAI) to deploy an agent in the program and found where Docker stores volumes (non-standard Linux location), however now I am getting an error that I believe is also caused by the non-standard implementation on Linux used by the NAS OS. This error happens when I go to start the service when following the stops in the video linked above. The error I am getting is "starting container failed: error creating external connectivity network: cannot restrict inter-container communication: please ensure that br_netfilter kernel module is loaded"

The response I got from Asustor Support is

> The kernel module is in the [NAS OS].
>
> So if you want you to need to manually insert the module to have it
> working.
>
> But please note that we have not yet tested it so there might be a
> risk to the stability of the system.

I have located the filepath of the kernal module by logging in via SSH but I do not know what I need to do in regards to inserting the module as the Asustor support team told me to do.

[Screenshot of Portainer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZvId.png)

Comment: The command `modprobe br_netfilter` should load the module, but you need to run it as root. That change will not persist across reboots. If it is a standard-ish Linux environment, there may be a file called `/etc/modules` that lists extra modules to loaded during system boot, so you could list the `br_netfilter` module in that file.

Comment: Thanks @IanAbbott I'll give that a try and report back

Comment: @IanAbbott Good news, the `modprobe` command worked, the `/etc/modules` file did not